# Unexpected behavior of numpy.fft.fft with high precision numbers

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have the following code...Note the two lines under # generate sine curve.  One uses a higher precision value for 2pi than the other, they should still give near identical results though.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


t1 = np.arange(0., 1., .01)

# generate sine curve
y1 = np.sin(6.28318*5.*t1)  
#y1 = np.sin(6.283185307179586*5.*t1) # equivalent to np.sin(2*np.pi*t1)

# calculate the fft (no averaging!) of the time series
ffty = np.fft.fft(y1)

fig, ax_list = plt.subplots(3,1)
ax_list[0].plot(t1,y1, '.-')

ax_list[1].plot(ffty.real, '.-', label='Real Part')
ax_list[1].legend()

ax_list[2].plot(ffty.imag, '.-', label='Imag Part')
ax_list[2].legend()


plt.show()
```

If you run the code with the lower precision 6.28318 you get the expected result for the fft...
[image]

However, if you run the code with the higher precision 6.283185307179586 which is equal to 2.*numpy.pi, you get the unexpected result below... the real part is drastically wrong...The amplitudes are way off, it's not symmetric, it doesn't make any sense.
[image]

I'm at a loss as to what is causing this.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: there is no useful difference.  5e-14 is approximately zero, and almost all floating point numbers are approximations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is totally expected behavior. Computers use floating-point computations, which are inherently imprecise.

Note the y-axis for your real result. If no numerical inaccuracy existed, the real component would be identically 0. With your "higher precision" result, the real part is almost identical to 0 (1e-14 is very close to the precision of double-precision floats). With a lower precision, the real part becomes much larger (though still much, much smaller than the imaginary part). Because of the larger numbers, there is more structure as well (i.e. the error is not given by rounding errors, but by an actual feature of your input data, a period that is slightly shorter than ideal).

Comment: So you are saying that if I use numpy.pi  in numpy.sin to generate a sine wave, and then put that into numpy.fft.fft ... and get gibberish out for the real part of the result...that that is expected behavior?

No

Comment: @JWebster: It is not gibberish, it is rounding errors. You did notice the "1e-14" at the top of that y-axis, right? If you really expect double-precision float computations to be error-free, you need to do some more reading. You could start here: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic, by David Goldberg](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @JWebster: Please add `ax_list[1].set_ylim((-50,50)); ax_list[2].set_ylim((-50,50))` to your code, to scale the real and imaginary components equally. I think this will help you see the "magnitude" of the problem in the correct light. :)

Comment: what are you talking about?  If I generate a sine wave using 

mysine = numpy.sin(numpy.pi * t)

and take the fft of it with 

numpy.fft.fft(mysine)

Then I'd better not get nonsense for a result

And the middle plot in the second set of plots is without a doubt, nonsense.

Comment: @JWebster: OK, if that is what you want to believe, so be it. Good luck finding an FFT tool that gives you something different. Set the axis limits like I suggested, and tell me again how the real part differs from zero.

Comment: huh...so maybe this is a teachable moment for me.  Does this mean that the error is actually that there are spikes at 5 Hz at all in the "low precision" real portion? And that the correct result is the "high precision" case where all the values are pretty much zero? I can see that...I guess I was just expecting spikes at 5 Hz, so when I didn't see them...

Also I was looking for the results to be mirrored in positive and negative frequencies, but yeah, that's just floating point stuff

Comment: @JWebster: Yes, the sine has a purely imaginary frequency spectrum. Note that the noise variance is larger where the imaginary component is larger -- the complex value has a larger magnitude, and hence the rounding error is larger too. This is why there's a peak in the real part in the second case. In the first case, because your period is slightly smaller than ideal, the signal is not exactly odd, and therefore the transform is not exactly purely imaginary, it has a small real component to go with the small even component of the spatial domain.

Answer (score 6):

As @Cris Luengo said you need to look at the scale of the y-axis to accurately compare two plots.  Another way to do this is to plot both of the things you're trying to compare on the same figure, as I've done below.

The magnitude of the FFT is displayed, using a log scale, and it's quite evident that using fewer significant figures of pi does indeed result in a lower accuracy result.
Most of the values aren't exactly zero, as is to be expected when using floating point numbers, but using more significant figures gives many orders of magnitude improvement, which is not immediately apparent when the FFTs are plotted separately.
[image: overlayed fft for various precisions]

code used:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


t1 = np.arange(0., 1., .01)

values = {
'low':6.28318,
'higher':6.283185307179586,
'highest':2*numpy.pi,
}
styles = {
'low':'-',
'higher':'-',
'highest':'.-'
}

fig, ax_list = plt.subplots(3,1)
for name, tau in values.items():
    y1 = np.sin(tau*5.*t1)
    ffty = np.fft.fft(y1)

    ax_list[0].plot(t1,y1, styles[name], label=name)
    ax_list[1].plot(abs(ffty.real), styles[name],label=name)
    ax_list[2].plot(abs(ffty.imag), styles[name], label=name)

[ax.legend() for ax in ax_list]
ax_list[0].set_title('time domain')
ax_list[1].set_title('real part')
ax_list[2].set_title('imaginary part')
ax_list[1].set_yscale('log')
ax_list[2].set_yscale('log')
plt.draw()
```